# Which (default) fonts contain the Windows/Apple logo?

Tags: windows-7, mac, fonts, window, utf-8

I'm looking for fonts which are installed on Windows respectively Apple by default which contain either the Windows or Apple-logo .

According to [this article](http://hea-www.harvard.edu/~fine/OSX/unicode_apple_logo.html) it should be character

> `U+F8FF` (decimal value `63743`, or on the web as either `&#xF8FF;` or `&#63743;`)

I know that this is not part of the Unicode-standard but still I'd like to know it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Wingdings, most?

U+F8FF is (in a way) part of the Unicode standard as the last of the [private use](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/U%2BF8FF) characters - so it's appearance is not standardised by Unicode.

> Some early Tengwar fonts map Elvish characters to it. The Imitari font
> draws it as a capital eth.
>
> The font Luxi draws it as the euro symbol.
>
> The font "Standard Symbols L" uses it as one of the box drawing
> characters.
>
> The official PRC standard on precomposed Tibetan uses the
> codepoint for the Tibetan syllable "hwo".
>
> Some font makers place a
> copyright statement or other creator's mark at that code point. For
> example, the dingbats font "DavysDingbats" uses it to display a face,
> presumably that of the font's creator.
>
> **In most Apple-supplied fonts,
> it represents the Apple logo, or an early version of the command key.**
>
> On Macintosh computers with the US keyboard layout active, the
> keyboard shortcut for the symbol is Option-Shift-K.
>
> The ConScript
> Unicode Registry suggests it be used for the Klingon glyph "KLINGON
> MUMMIFICATION GLYPH." This is followed by e.g. Code2000.
>
> **In Wingdings
> 1,  is the Windows logo. In some computers, however, it is  (U+F000)
> instead of .**

Note: On XP, Wingdings has the MS Windows logo at 0xFF.

Answer (score 3):

On Mac OS 10.6:

[image]

For some reason, the 10.7 CharacterPalette doesn't show font variation for PUA glyphs.

<sub>The CharacterPalette.app from 10.6 works on 10.7 as well, but I only realized it after taking those screenshots.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Very old post. The answers where already given 11 years ago: the Apple and Windows logos are not included in Unicode. On Mac, most fonts have the Apple logo in the Private Use Area at `U+F8FF`, but I'm not aware of any fonts on Windows or other OS'es supporting this. Windows has the Windows logo in the wingdings fonts at `U+00FF`, but support for the wingdings-fonts in browsers or outside windows is poor. Because of this, I use widely supported symbols that are similar to the logos.

Instead of the apple logo, I use `U+1F34E` ︎ (or `U+1F34E U+FE0E` to prevent this being displayed as emoji). Instead of the Windows logo, I use `U+229E` ⊞.

These symbols are not the same as the real logos but the user will recognize what you mean.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Before answering an old question having an accepted answer (look for green ✓) as well as other answers ensure your answer adds something new or is otherwise helpful in relation to them. Here is a guide on [answer]. There is also a site [tour] and  a [help].